# Css and Js files are added correctly but not working in Laravel 5.6

Tags: javascript, php, css, laravel-5.6

I'm gonna add a template to my laravel, I put template files in public folder and as always, I use the following command to load its files:

```
<link href="{{ asset('admin-panel') }}/dist/css/bootstrap-rtl.min.css">
<script src="{{ asset('admin-panel') }}/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

None of the files are loaded. In **"view page source"**, the path of files is correct and files are opened But they do not work. What should I do?

Comment: Do they work when you run the site with the command `php artisan serve`?

Comment: No, Files still do not work.

Comment: I added an another template for a part of project. And they load without any problems.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? If everything is loaded properly, what **exactly** is not working?

Comment: @NicoHaase, My template would not be fully loaded without `rel="stylesheet"` in `link` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first I wanted to delete the question, but for some it may be interesting that the use of `rel="stylesheet"` in the `link` tag is mandatory in Laravel projects. Because this template runs well without being used in Laravel.

```
<link href="{{ asset('admin-panel') }}/dist/css/bootstrap-rtl.min.css">
```

Change to:

```
<link href="{{ asset('admin-panel') }}/dist/css/bootstrap-rtl.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```